# Error converting data type varchar to float isnumeric = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I run the script:

```
select 
    cast(s as float)
from 
    t
where 
    ISNUMERIC(s) = 1
```

it stops with the error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Why does it happen? I'm trying to convert to float only numerics. How do I found out which row causes the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The isnumeric function thinks just about everything is a number. Use "try_convert" instead. if the value can't convert to your destination datatype, it returns null.

```
select convert(float, '1,0,1')
where try_convert(float, '1,0,1') is not null
```

If you are on an older version of SQL, I would write my own function.

Comment: try_convert is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`ISNUMERIC()` function will return `1` for values like `123e3` because these values are Interpreted as numeric values. Because sql server sees this as `123 , 3 to the powers of 10` which is really a numeric value.

You should try something like....

```
Select * 
From tableName 
WHERE Col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

This will return any row where there is a non-numeric character, even values with a `.`.

Comment: Very interesting. Why is that value considered  a numeric in your example?

Comment: `123e2` sql server sees this as `123 , 2 to the powers of 10` which is really a numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

I usually face with this when the value in a column you are trying to convert to float contains a comma (,) as thousand separator:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('140,523.86')
```

The Result is 1, but unable to cast it as a float.
By replacing it works fine for me:

```
SELECT
   CAST( replace(s,',','') AS float ) AS Result
FROM t
WHERE ISNUMERIC(replace(s,',','')) = 1
```

Comment: While this would work, there are some interesting cases in which a non-conventional number will return positive with this function; case in point, 1e4.